# Can I install fresh Linux accross partitions (LUKS & LVM) and preserve/use existing home user?

Tags: upgrade, encryption, fedora, logical-drive

With an existing LUKS encrypted logical volume partitioned hard disk dual boot to Windoz and Linux (Fedora 15), is it necessary to "start over" with the LUKS setup when upgrading the system?

I recall some note about dividing the Linux installation over different partitions would help to preserve the home data in future update  (I can't find this now) Before I try it, is this possible and intended use case for partitioning a Linux installation?

```
   # lsblk -fa
   NAME                                                 FSTYPE      LABEL         MOUNTPOINT
   sda [80G]
   ├─sda1 [system W95 FAT 32]                           vfat
   ├─sda2                                               ext4              /boot
   └─sda3 [52.4G]                                       crypto_LUKS
     └─luks-de25ac97-6a32-4b79-a6a0-296a39376b3b (dm-0) LVM2_member
       ├─cryptVG-root (dm-1) [21.5G]                    ext4              /
       ├─cryptVG-swap (dm-2) [5.4MB]                    swap              [SWAP]
       └─cryptVG-data (dm-3) [25.6G]                    ext4              /home
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely "Not".

It does not appear possible with Fedora and Anaconda to use/preserve an existing home partition in the installer wizard. While the wizard does recognize a drive with a previous version of Linux, it doesn't seem to do any work to "recognize" an existing /home partition.

Fedora's Documentation for [F17 Installation](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/17/html/Installation_Guide/sn-upgrading-system-x86.html) has a "sticky note":

> "If you are re-installing the same version of Fedora, preserve your
>   user data by placing it on a separate /home partition. "

Evidently, if its necessary to re-install the same version, Anaconda will recognize the /home partition and preserve it as part of a *Rescue* use case. Only, I'm used to seeing unavailable options *ghosted*. (>_<)

Answer (score 0):

You should better use manual installation from live cd or existing Linux system on another partition in chroot.

Let's assume that you are in rescue/live cd Linux system.
Firstly you should mount your encrypted luks partition into /mnt

```
su -
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 cryptLVM
```

Then create all necessary directories:

```
mkdir /mnt/{home,proc,dev,sys}
```

And mount LVM:

```
mount /dev/mapper/cryptVG-root /mnt
mount /dev/mapper/cryptVG-data /mnt/home
```

Then mount all system file systems:

```
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

Now chroot and proceed with installation:

```
chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

This [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemLVMHowto) may be helpful for you.

Comment: The mount command does not work properly. Either it warns: `mount: you must specify the filesystem type` Or when I add `-t ext4` mount produces the error: `mount: special device /dev/mapper/cryptVG-data does not exist` What are we missing here?

Comment: Please check /dev/mapper/ for existing devices there, seems like luksOpen is not enough, you should also enable LVM volumes with vgchange -a y and then mount volumes that will appear in /dev/mapper