# Why does LVM HDD fail "mount" command when booting from CDROM?

Tags: mount, lvm, fsck, luks

Currently I have a [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/434707/can-i-install-fresh-linux-accross-partitions-luks-lvm-and-preserve-use-exist) asking if I can install/upgrade existing LUKS/LVM without having to erase and rebuild the partitions. This has provided instructions to mount the HDD, but there are errors. I've reprinted the steps below and indicated the error I'm experiencing. [Another post](https://superuser.com/questions/116617/how-to-mount-lvm-volume) on the same topic offers the same advise, but doesn't seem to have the same problems that I'm having.

My goal is to determine if I can upgrade using the existing LUKS and LVM. However, the problem is the same if I wanted to perform `fsck` operations on my internal HDD booting from LIVE media CD.

One: Open up the encrypted volume

```
 su -
 cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda3 cryptLVM
```

Two: Create all necessary directories:

```
2. 
mkdir /mnt/{home,proc,dev,sys}
```

Three: Mount LVM:

```
3. 
mount /dev/mapper/cryptVG-root /mnt
mount /dev/mapper/cryptVG-data /mnt/home
```

Four: Mount all system file systems:

```
4.
mount -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
```

The trouble occurs between 3-4.

```
> mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

If I specify `-t ext4`, then I get another error.

```
> mount: special device /dev/mapper/cryptVG-data does not exist
```

UPDATE: I also have a [post](https://superuser.com/questions/434759/is-luks-cryptsetups-hddname-or-name-simply-an-arbitrary-label-used-during) about the LUKS/cryptsetup `name` value as I try to figure out how these actions cooperate to mount HDD.

Comment: Don't you need to tell LVM to rescan for volumes after unlocking the encrypted volume? I don't know anything about LVM, admittedly, but `vgscan`/`pvscan` look relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your setup, you may need to explicitly enable the corresponding volume group before or after using cryptsetup.

As already mentioned in [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/436533/why-does-mount-fail-on-hdd-when-booting-from-cdrom#comment503820_436533), try `vgscan` and/or `vgdisplay` first.

You can then enable all available logical volumes in the volume group with `vgchange -ay`.

Comment: I just tried the vgscan and vgdisplay commands. They only seem to report info (unless the Man page is incomplete). I'm guessing the suggestion is to use them to learn the vg_name for vgchange command?

Comment: @xtian Correct. But you can just use `vgchange -ay` without any other parameters. This will enable all available logical volumes of all available volume groups.